# Select2 mutiple select with ctrl error

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 jQuery and geting error in multiple select. when any user select one by one then maximumSelectionLength work, if user press ctrl and select multiple option then maximum selection is not working and user can select more then 3 options

```
$(function() {
  $('select').select2({
          maximumSelectionLength: 3,
    });
});
```

example : [jQuery select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple-max) >> Limiting the number of selections

try this with ctrl + select and without ctrl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is not clear. i think you are intrested in multiple tagging.

In that scenario i suggest you to use select2 multiple tagging(of select2 pluging).

in tagging method you can have multiple tags.

you can apply select2 for this input field.

```
<input type="hidden" id="tags" style="width: 300px" />
```

here is **demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/avqfjc33/14/

Comment: i think what @Harman says is : in the select2 control, when you press CTRL , then it allows to select more than maximumSelectionLength elements.

Answer (score 1):

@Harman : override the select2:selecting function as below.

```
$(function() {
    $('select').select2({
          maximumSelectionLength: 3,
    });

    $("select").on("select2:selecting", function (e) {
        if ($(this).val() && $(this).val().length >= 3) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```